# how to allow multiple rdp different session with the same user in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I have xrdp server running on my ubuntu 19.04 machine. I can have multiple xfce4-sessions but with different users.
 I want to have multiple different sessions with the same user.